# Multiple Categories not working with MSTEST command-line

Tags: visual-studio, mstest

I am trying to use MSTEST to run visual studio tests, but when I try to use /category:"&" the tests won't run, and it will say that it does not recognize the category.

I want to run multiple categories at once without using different MSTEST calls so that in one MSTEST call I can run all of the categories and publish one output results file.

My categories are correct because it runs successfully with 1 category, I'm just having trouble appending them.

For example,

```
mstest  /testcontainer:.(...).dll  /testcontainer:.(...).dll /category:"Defect Tests&Functional Tests"
```

returns

```
Loading .\(...).testrunconfig
Loading .\(...).dll
Loading .\(...).dll
Starting execution...
No tests to execute.
```

However, if I were to use just one category, say:

```
\category:"Defect Tests"
```

It would work totally fine.

Comment: The documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx#category is clear. Please [edit] your question to show examples of your command lines that work and of those that do not work.

Comment: Updated with examples

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't realize that I should use | as the literal OR logical operator, and not something else. I was using & and was ending up with no tests to run, because I thought it would run both test suites, but in reality, it was only running tests that had both category labels on them... which was none of them.

For Example (based on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx#category):

```
/category:"group1|group2" runs tests that are in test category "group1" or "group2". 
                          Tests that are in both categories will also be run.

/category:!group1&!group2  exclude tests with categories "group1" and "group2".

/category:group1 runs tests in the test category "group1".

/category:"group1&group2" runs tests that are in both test categories "group1" and "group2." Tests that are only in one of the specified test categories will not be run.


/category:"group1&!group2" runs tests from the test category "group1" that are not in the test category "group2." A test that is in both test category "group1" and "group2" will not be run.
```